# Spring constrction autowired vs property autowired

Tags: spring, autowired

This is my code

```
@Autowired
private Temp tempProp;

@Autowired
public Batch(Temp tempConst) {
        System.out.println(tempProp.test);   
}
```

Batch is configured in XML and Temp is configured using @Component annotation. 
Why is tempConst injected correctly but tempProp is still null?
Even if i add a setTempProp with @autowired annotation, tempProp is still null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a bean named tempProp?

Comment: No. Just Temp. Autowired looks 'by Type' by default. Isn't it?

Comment: yes it works like it but I don't know priority between them.

Comment: Is there any difference between configuring a bean in xml and using @Component. Autowiring the property or setter method does not work in the example I gave. Only autowiring the constructor works.